# Can't correctly configure iptables for nodemailer

Tags: node.js, gmail, ubuntu-16.04, iptables, nodemailer

I stuck on an issue for send mail...
I have a server running Ubuntu 16.04, and on this server, I run (with [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)) a node.js server. This server must send me an email when I ask for. That worked fine but then I configured iptables and now the nodejs server can't send mail anymore...
I configured iptables like this :

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request limit: avg 1/sec burst 5
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/RST limit: avg 1/sec burst 5

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ntp
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
```

When I accept all output (`iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`), the mail is correctly sended, so I assume the problem is somewhere in the chain OUTPUT, but I don't find it. I tried a lot of solution finded on internet but no one work in my case.
Also, I use [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) to send mail, and I use gmail as service.
Here my email config :

```
module.exports = {
    config: {

        service: 'gmail',
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: 'my.sender.adress@gmail.com',
            pass: '********'
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    },
    receiver: "my.personnal.adress@gmail.com"
};
```

I hope somebody will see clearer than me on this point... 
Thank for reading and have a nice day !

Comment: Could you allow port 465 and 587 for outgoing packets on output table.

Comment: I've already try this : `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT` + `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT` but it's make no difference and I don't understand why because it's look like the ports we are using here (the node console say it's the port 465).

Comment: Okey then try to allow new connections with state NEW,edit the first rule for this.maybe it is the problem.also allow port 465 at the same time.

Comment: If I edit the first line to `ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED`, it works, but I think it ins't the right way to do because I even no need to allow the port 465 for it works. So I guess it just accept all new connections in output, no matter what port is it.